# Weka: Src and Dest differ in # of attributes after I do feature selection on the training set

Tags: weka

I am trying to use weka to classify text. What I do is this:

- I create on big ARFF file with all of the data: `all_of_it.arff`.
- I split that data into training and test:`train.arff` and `test.arff`
- I do feature selection on the training set and output a new training file:`train_fs.arff`
- I build a classifier with only those selected features.

And the problem is.....

I don't quite know how to standardize the test set to only use the features I selected from the training set. Something like **create new test file from `test.arff` according to `train_fs.arff`**

*I tried using

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Standardize -b -i train_fs.arff -o train2.arff -r test.arff -s test2.arff
```

but I got the infamous `Src and Dest differ in # of attributes`.

Is there any way to normalize/standardize the sets according to an arff file (namely my new training data with few features) I don't see how to do this with the Standardize or StringToWordVector filter.

Answer (score 1):

**Batch filtering is one solution to your problem.**

Pros:

- It will apply the same filter to your test dataset as you apply to your training dataset.  When you perform feature selection, the two datasets will be compatible

Cons:

- It is only availabe from the command line interface or Weka's Java API
- The two datasets must be filtered at the same time

You can read more about Batch filtering [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Batch+filtering).

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look into [InputMappedClassifier](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/misc/InputMappedClassifier.html). It is a wrapper classifier that addresses incompatible training and testing data.